# DHTMLX Scheduler MVC - Load data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

**Heya**,

I've been using this template for some days and I understand some necessary requirements, now, I just need to make some adjustments in order to load and view data from my **MS SQL** DB.

I'm using **EF Code First** and I set some configurations on the controller already.

This template requires four mandatory fields which are: ***id, text, start_date and end_date***.

Now, my issue is: the table I have got on my **MS SQL** DB has many more fields and the four ones that represent the data I need have different names also.
What I'm trying to accomplish for now is to load the calendar and see just one event I created on my DB as an example.

My DB fields are these:
***id* -> ckeyid

*text* -> texto

*start_date* -> data + hinicio

*end_date* -> data + hfim**

How can I possibly tell the controller that these four fields of my table are the ones the Scheduler should use?

Best regards,
Granvic

Comment: This question is not related to sql-server. please use tags properly.

Comment: Sorry about that @FLICKER, already improved the tags.